# Compare size of directory with the free space in disk

Tags: bash

Im creating a script which compare a size of a folder /home/user/files with a free space in /backups to ensure the copy can be done.

These returns size in (blocks?) and route

> du -B 1 /home/user/files | cut -f 1 -d " "

> 12288   /home/user/files

But this returns in GB:

> df -h /var | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'
>
> 3.9G

And cant verifi with an if.

How can i get the same type of measure (blocks, kb...) and compare it to ensure free space is also to make a copy?

Thx!

Comment: `df` also has options on reporting size units. `-h` is working against you here. Hint: `df -b`.

Comment: You can use `df -BM /var`

Comment: df -BM /var
Returns in MB:


Filesystem     1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1          9511M 5045M     3964M  57% /



du -B 1 /home/jag/Descargas | cut -f 1 -d " "
12288   /home/jag/Descargas